# What the Hierarchy of the UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

As we know, the `UICollectionView` contains background view and cells and supply view, how the hierarchy of it? If the `UICollectionView` add a subview, how's the subview's hierarchy?

Comment: Basically, you probably shouldn't add your own subviews to a collection view. Let the collection view manage its contents.

Comment: if you need extra header & footer view for `UICollectionView`, consider this way: http://www.appcoda.com/supplementary-view-uicollectionview-flow-layout/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIViewController` holding the `UICollectionView` -> `UICollectionView` -> `backgroundView` -> `UICollectionViewCell`.

Any subviews can be reordered, but are added above the cells.

[image: Window]

Related reading (and image source):

[UICollectionView’s backgroundView property is horribly broken](http://blog.spacemanlabs.com/2013/11/uicollectionviews-backgroundview-property-is-horribly-broken/)